# How to display 2 random numbers and store it to the users cache based on the page URL with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code here:

```js
const stored = localStorage[location.href]
const number = stored || Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2

document.getElementById("n1").innerHTML = number

if ( !stored ) localStorage[location.href] = number
```

```html
<div>
 The first number is <span id="n1"></span>.
</div>
```

That displays a random number between 2~6 and that saves that to the user's cache mapped by the page URL, so if the user reloads the page the same number will appear again, but if the user goes to a different page with the same code it will generate another number between 2~6.

In sum:

If the user first load my website and number 3 is generated, then number 3 is displayed, if the user returns to the same website the number 3 will keep been displayed, but if the user goes to another URL within my website with the same code, then it should generate another number.

But what I am trying to do now is to display a second number, different from the first number but with the same "local storing mechanism" to work like the first number. But I can't just change the variables in my code and the local storage key - `localStorage[location.href]` - since this key is used to map the localstorage to the pages URL.

Is there any way that I can use my code to make it generate 2 random numbers and store it in the user cache, and make this numbers keep the same if the user reloads the same page, but change to a different number if the user goes to a different page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you could could store an array in the localStorage value.

Comment: how different are your urls? Are subdomains? or is the relative path at the end different? Maybe, rather than using `location.href` directly, you could extract the domain and use that as a key to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, your requirement is to store two values for the same key in localStorage. Since localStorage stores only string values, you can store an array of 2 numbers after converting it into a string.

```
const stored = localStorage[location.href] 
const numbers = stored && JSON.parse(stored) || [Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2]

document.getElementById("n1").innerHTML = numbers[0]
document.getElementById("n2").innerHTML = numbers[1]

if ( !stored ) localStorage[location.href] = JSON.stringify(numbers)
```

Or you could always use two keys like `localStorage[location.href+'1']` and `localStorage[location.href+'2']`

Comment: I used localStorage[location.href+'1'] and localStorage[location.href+'2'] and it worked just as I wanted, thanks a lot